# I am trying to map over an array and add comma's in between each instance except for the last

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to list the names of all the users returned from my backend. I chose not to place them in a `<ul>` or `<ol>`because I want them to display inline with one another separated by commas. I am wondering what the best way would be to add commas after each name except the last right now I am mapping over the value like this:

```
 <p>
  You have notes for the following users that are overdue:
     {list && list.map((items) => <> {items.userName},</>)}
 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
<p>
    You have notes for the following users that are overdue:
    { list && list.map((items) => items.userName).join(',') }
</p>
```

---

If you want those names are in separate tags, you can also achieve that by utilizing css:

```js
<p>
    You have notes for the following users that are overdue:
    {list && list.map((items) => <span class="name">{items.userName}</span>)}
</p>
```

```css
p .name:not(:last-of-type)::after {
    content: ',';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! For some reason when I try the .join(', ') after i map over the list it displays my usernames as [object, Object]. I never understand why this happens. The second solution you provided offers the same output as `<> {items.userName},</>`  where it places commas after every instance including the last.